# How to prevent an object from leaving screen in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, screen, bounds

I know there are a couple other questions regarding this but none of them seem to work or they all are incomplete or half complete. I need to know how to keep an object within the visible screen! So I have a spaceship sprite that uses the device's tilt and core motion to fly across the screen. If I tilt my device, the spaceship will at one point leave my screen and continue going in that direction. How do I keep the spaceship stay inside my screen so that even if I tilt to the left or right it will never leave the visible screen? Here is some of my code to the spaceship.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var ship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
let manager = CMMotionManager()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    ship.xScale = 1/5
    ship.yScale = 1/5
    ship.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/(2), y: self.frame.height/1.5)

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
        (data, error) in

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)! * 15), CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)! * 15))

    }

    ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

    self.addChild(ship)

}
```

I already tried self.view?.bounds and making it into a physics body but my spaceship never comes into contact with it.

Comment: Do you want it to 'bounce' off the edges of the screen or to just not move past the screen boundary?

Comment: Try replacing `ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()` with `ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:ship.size.width/2)` and add an `edgeLoopFromRect` around your scene.

Comment: I want it to not move past screen boundary.

Comment: You'll need to set the `restitution` property of the ship and the edge to 0.

Comment: @0x141E It somewhat worked! I tried adding a edgeLoopFromRect but it didn't worked so what I did was I added this bit: let edgeFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX - 300,y: self.frame.minY), size: self.frame.size)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: edgeFrame)                                                                                                    This seemed to make a boundary on the top, right, and bottom part of my view. The only problem was the left side. My spaceship can still fly through the left side of my screen.

Comment: I suspect that `self` (the scene) does not match the size of the view. Try changing its size by editing `GameScene.sks` and then use `self.frame` as the argument for the edge loop.

Comment: @0x141E No it doesn't work. There is only boundaries for the top and bottom when I try it with self.frame.

Comment: Which device (e.g., iPhone 6) are you using to test your game?

Comment: A I-Pod . Anyways I got an answer

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was meddle around with the size of the screen in the .sks file. I specifically made mine 800x640 because I am testing on an I-Pod 5. Then I added this bit of code:

```
let edgeFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: ((self.view?.frame.minX)! + 200) ,y: (self.view?.frame.minY)!), size: CGSize(width: (self.view?.frame.width)! + 90, height: (self.view?.frame.height)! + 90))
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: edgeFrame)
```

This made a proper boundary around my screen and did not allow my spaceship to leave the screen. Best of all this was a perfect fit so if you are testing on a different device then just adjust the width and height numbers as needed. Remember to also adjust your .sks screen size.

Credits to 0x141E for hinting me in the right direction.